# VScode not obeying "Tab Size" setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

VScode is ignoring the Tab Size setting.

I'm using VScode to edit some c++ code.  I have

```
editor.DetectIndentation: false
editor.InsertSpaces: true
editor.TabSize: 4
```

set in both User and Workspace.  I have tried restarting the editor.
At the bottom of the window it says:

```
Spaces:4  UTF-8 LF C++ Linux
```

When I type in lines, tab inserts 4 spaces, but when I format the document (Ctrl-Shift-I), everything reverts back to 2-space indentation.

I have no .editorconfig file

Were is the magic setting that's over riding my TabSize of 4?

Thanks.

Comment: You casing is wrong. Is that just a typo in writing your question post? Or did you really write it like that in your settings.json? It should be `editor.detectIndentation`, `editor.insertSpaces`, and `editor.tabSize`.

Comment: That was a typo.  In fact, I didn't put those in a config file, I set them in the UI.

Comment: I suspect strongly that a recent update to VSCode has re-introduced a bug with how `editor.tabSize` is used. It appears that it is no longer obeyed and always defaults to 2 spaces. I've been finding many answers to this same question asked a few years ago and at some point, the answers given solved the issue; however, this is no longer the case AFAIK. This is quite frustrating! I would love to find out that this has finally been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the culprit was the setting: `C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style`

It was set to `Google`.  I guess Google likes 2 spaces for their C++ code. I changed it to `Visual Studio` which uses 4 spaces.  The upshot is that the tabSize is ignored if the format style uses something else.